# mysql selecting only top 1 from subgroup

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query from a mysql table that results in a dataset as follows

| car | colour | sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Benz | Black | 2 |
| Benz | White | 1 |
| BMW | Black | 3 |
| BMW | Green | 2 |
| BMW | Blue | 1 |
| Toyota | Yellow | 7 |
| Toyota | Red | 5 |
| Toyota | Blue | 3 |
| Toyota | White | 1 |

I'm trying to select the top sold row from each subrow, so my final dataset would be:

| car | colour | sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Benz | Black | 2 |
| BMW | Black | 3 |
| Toyota | Yellow | 7 |

Order doesn't matter i just need to make sure its the top colour sold for that particular car. I tried using distinct, but that applies to the whole row. I tried using group by that selects a random sold amount not the top one. Any idea what query I should be running for this? Is using subqueries inevitable? its a rather small dataset of about ~100 entries. But id rather not use subqueries for future scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the function `RANK()`in a CTE.
See the dbFiddle link at the bottom for the schema and further testing.
NB: This will not function with older version of mySQL.

> ```
> with rankedSales as (
> select 
>   car,
>   colour,
>   sold,
>   rank() over (partition by car order by sold desc) rn
> from carSales)
> select
>   car, 
>   colour,
>   sold
> from rankedSales
> where rn = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> car    | colour | sold
> :----- | :----- | ---:
> Benz   | Black  |    2
> BMW    | Black  |    3
> Toyota | Yellow |    7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0578f1db070d97e7c47bd1b931a8eec9)*